# Fill height of absolute positioning children

Tags: css, html

I have the following problem:
I need to display informations in 2 columns first column should have static width, and second column should fill width to the resolution of page.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3AvdP/1/) is my solution for this, but it doesn't work completely correct. I have used `box-sizing: border-box` and `position: absolute` for this but with this parent of the record ignore height of the absolute positioning children.

I need to show all the content of each column. I also have some **restrictions**: solution should be compatible with IE9 so I cannot use flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two compatible solutions here:

- First using `box-sizing` you are close but remove the `position:absolute`

  The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/3AvdP/21/**
- Two using `calc` for the width:

  The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/3AvdP/20/**

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the parent element to `display: table; width: 100%;` and the columns `display: table-cell;` and a width for the fixed width column. This will set your fixed column to a specific width and then use the other column to fill the rest.